# Counting an array has twice the expected number of elements

Tags: bash, array

Why does `bash` appear to count the words in an array rather than the number of elements?

```
touch '1 red' '2 orange' '3 yellow'        # Three filenames, each of two words

files=( * )                                # Get the set of files
echo "#files is ${#files}"

for (( i=0; i <= ${#files}; i++ ))
do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${files[$i]}"
done
```

The output from this seems "wrong". For starters, `${#files}` contains `5`, showing that there are six elements in `${files[@]}`. However, only elements `0`, `1`, and `2` of `${files[@]}` contain any data, and those contain the correct filenames:

```
#files is 5
0       1 red
1       2 orange
2       3 yellow
3
4
5
```

I would have expected either `${files[@]}` to contain the six words `1`, `red`, `2`, `orange`, `3`, and `yellow`, or `${#files}` to be `2`. Not this mixed scenario.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me, please?

Comment: Try `echo "${#files[@]}"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${#files}` is the length of the first element of the array, i.e. the length of `1 red`. Which is five.

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

> ${#name[subscript]} expands to the length of ${name[subscript]}. If subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the expansion is the number of elements in the array.   [...]
>   Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0.

So, `${#files}` = `${#files[0]}`. But `${#files[@]}` or `${#files[*]}` give the number of elements in the array.

(It has nothing to do with the number of words, though if you expand `${files[*]}` without quotes, you get the usual word splitting over all the values.)

Comment: Bit of an annoying feature, I'd say, but I guess it's in line with conflating `${array[0]}` with `$array`.

Comment: If it's counting words in the 0th element, why does `${#files}` in my example show 5 not 2 (or 1)?

Comment: It's not counting words, just the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Please Change `${#files}"` to `${#files[@]}"`

You are getting 5 from `${#files}"` because that is the first file.
Equivalent to `${files[0]}`, which is named '1 red'.
That *string* contains 5 characters.

The loop fails for the same problem, it iterates from 1 to 5.
However, elements 3, 4 and 5 are simply null (unset).